# Angular upload multiple images with preview

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

for my own app i want an image uploader, where i can upload multiple images and preview them.

I am trying to make it look like this . [image]

(copied this from another website)

I tried following this tutorial, but i can not upload anything at all.

https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-13-image-upload-preview/
[image]

Is there a working example or someone know why it is not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the tutorial, you need to connect your application to some kind of storage where the images can be stored.

[image]

For example, when you want to post those images via Rest to an existing HTTP-endpoint, you need to follow the tutorial behind the first link. Until now, you only developed the frontend part of the functionality.